# Automatically add parameters to get_results()

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I want to call the method `$wpdb->get_results()`,
and I need to add parameters (WHERE clauses) to the SQL query.
The thing is, I want to build a generic function that will receive a parameters object and will generate an SQL query which includes my parameters.

So, for example, if this is my base query:

```
$taxis = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table", ARRAY_A); // base query
```

And these are my parameters:

```
$params = array(
  'color' => 'blue',
  'model' => 'ford'
);
```

It will call *get_results*  with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM $table WHERE color='blue' AND model='ford';
```

Is there a way to build a function that will have this behaviour?

***NOTES:**

1. I don't know how many parameters are going to be in the parameters object nor which parameters they will be (that is why it has to be generic).
2. I do know, (in my case) that the only SQL CLAUSES I am going to need are `WHERE =`.

Comment: Yes there is a way (probably more than one way in fact). you can just use a loop and some string concatenation. Although obviously you need make sure to build your query using prepared statements and paramters to avoid SQL injection and unescaped data vulnerabilities - that adds a little bit of complexity (i.e. building the parameters array at the same time as the WHERE clause) but not very much.

Comment: Whatever you do, please make sure to use `$wpdb->prepare()` on your query, which is WordPress’s way of prepared statements that ADyson mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the code comments for an explanation on what is happening in each step:

```php
<?php

// make sure this doesn't come from user input, as it is inserted into the query directly
$tableName = $wpdb->prefix . "yourtable";

$columnWhitelist = array( 'color', 'model' );

$params = array(
    'color' => 'blue',
    'model' => 'ford'
);

// filter param keys by allowed column names defined in $columnWhitelist
$params = array_filter(
    $params,
    function ( $key ) use ( $columnWhitelist )  {
        return in_array( $key, $columnWhitelist );
    },
    ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY
);

$whereClauseParts = array();

// put column/value pairs of $params into $placeholderValues array
$placeholderValues = array();
foreach ( $params as $column => $value) {
    $whereClauseParts[] = "`$column` = %s";
    $placeholderValues[] = $value;
}

// put together the WHERE clause with placeholders
$whereClause = implode(' AND ', $whereClauseParts );

// put together the whole query tring
$queryString = "SELECT * FROM `$tableName` WHERE " . $whereClause;

// you can use this to see what your prepared query will roughly look like,
// but with missing single quotes around the values 
// die( vsprintf(
//     $queryString,
//     $placeholderValues
// ) );

$wpdb->get_results(
    $wpdb->prepare(
        $queryString,
        $placeholderValues
    )
);
```

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot. Your code works and it helped me a lot!

Just one thing- 

In the `$queryString`, the column names are outputted wrapped with single quotes, 
which is not valid in a SQL query, which leads to an empty result.


How can I modify the for loop so it will output the column names without the quotes?

Current queryString:

`"SELECT * FROM 'wp_taxis' WHERE 'color' = 'blue' AND 'model' = 'Volvo'"`

Desired queryString:

`"SELECT * FROM 'wp_taxis' WHERE color = 'blue' AND model = 'Volvo'"`


Again, Thanks a lot! @Constantin Groß

Comment: You're absolutely right, of course! I wrote it from memory, outside of a wordpress context, so I didn't see the mistake. I updated the code to insert the column names directly. For that, I also implemented a whitelist for allowed column names to check against, which is a good idea anyway.